# Android - search box not appeared

Tags: java, android, xml

Why my search box not appeared inside my fragment? Is it because of `ListView`?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HashtagFragment" >

    <!-- Editext for Search -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search hashtags.."
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more property in Listview- "layout_below", as you are using RelativeLayout as parent-

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" />
```